# Localisation of multiple plurals in Qt

Tags: qt

For a simple sentence, I can use `%n` to generate rules for localisation of plurals. E.g. `showMessage(tr("%n message(s) saved", "", msgCount));`. In Qt I can also use `%1`, `%2` etc. to translate texts with positional arguments, e.g. `showMessage(tr("file %1 was copied to directory %2").arg(fileName).arg(dirPath));`.

Is there a way I can combine these two approaches for sentences like `showMessage(tr("found %n1 file(s) in %n2 directorie(s)").arg(fileCount).arg(dirCount));` which can contain multiple plurals? Note that I just made up these `%n1` and `%n2`, I know this is probably not how it is done. Or is it? Or do I have to somehow split the more complex sentences into simpler terms and translate the plurals one by one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I worked around the issue while still leaving space for translators to work their translations with some freedom :

```
QString fileStringPart = tr("%n file(s)", "", fileCount);
QString dirStringPart = tr("%n directorie(s)", "", dirCount);
message = tr("found %1 in %2 ").arg(fileStringPart).arg(dirStringPart));
```

Answer (score 1):

After a more thorough thinking about this question, I think I am asking nonsense. This is a combinatorial problem. If there were 2 terms which can be in singular or plural, we would need to provide 2 x 2 = 4 translations. If there were 3 terms, it would be 9. But there are languages where there are more forms of plural ('paucal' or others), so the number of combinations would explode quickly. I believe this is the reason why I cannot find Qt API for this problem. Let me know if you know of some hacks. The only solution I came up with is to split the text in a clever way and translate it per partes.

Comment: Having the exact same problem in december 2021, still without a solution. I will post here if I find any better one than your own.